# What is the difference between margin-block-start and margin-top?

Tags: html, css, margin

Trying to understand the core difference in usage between the two, but I fail to find an article or doc that details such a comparison. Taking the example provided [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start), assuming the following:

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.exampleText {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  margin-block-start: 20px;
  background-color: #c8c800;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="exampleText">Example text</p>
</div>
```

The difference between [this instance](https://jsfiddle.net/xuodgqL7/), and one in which `margin-top` [is used](https://jsfiddle.net/wy8rh9kb/), is quite small (however visible).

The [specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top) state that `margin-block-start` **depends on layout model** while `margin-top` **refer to the width of the containing block**. Would love it if someone could explain it in layman's term.

Comment: _refers to the width of the containing block._ This only applies when you are using percentages for the margin value. Percentages for values are *almost* always calculated using the width of the parent block. So, if you have a `margin-top` of `10%` and you increase the width of the containing block, it will be `10%` relative to the calculated width of the containing block.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the official<sup>1</sup> [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-logical/#propdef-margin-block-start) you can read:

> These properties correspond to the margin-top, margin-bottom, margin-left, and margin-right properties. The mapping depends on the element’s writing-mode, direction, and text-orientation.

By default, you will have the following mapping:

```
margin-block-start = margin-top
margin-block-end = margin-bottom
margin-inline-start = margin-left
margin-inline-end = margin-right
```

Example:

```css
.margin {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-right:200px;
}

.margin-alt {
  margin-block-start:50px;
  margin-block-end:10px;
  margin-inline-start:100px; 
  margin-inline-end:200px; 
}

div {
  border:2px solid;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin">
A
</div>
<hr>
<div class="margin-alt">
A
</div>
```

Now if we change the writing mode, you will see that we will have a different mapping.

```css
.margin {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-right:200px;
}

.margin-alt {
  margin-block-start:50px;
  margin-block-end:10px;
  margin-inline-start:100px; 
  margin-inline-end:200px; 
}

div {
  border:2px solid;
  padding:20px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin">
A
</div>
<hr>
<div class="margin-alt">
A
</div>
<div class="margin-alt" style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;">
A
</div>
```

In the above, you will notice when using `vertical-lr`  a mapping equal to

```
margin-block-start = margin-left
margin-block-end = margin-right
margin-inline-start = margin-top 
margin-inline-end = margin-bottom
```

and when using `vertical-rl`

```
margin-block-start = margin-right
margin-block-end = margin-left
margin-inline-start = margin-top 
margin-inline-end = margin-bottom
```

---

I will not detail all the cases, but basically each `margin-*-*` property will be mapped to a `margin-*` property based on the values of `writing-mode`, `direction`, and `text-orientation`.

You can play with the different values to see the different cases.

---

Your examples are a bit complex because you are having margin-collapsing and the default margin applied to `p` so it's difficult to understand.

Here is a better one:

```css
div:not([class]) {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.exampleText {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  margin-block-start: 20px; /* we will end with a margin-left */
  background-color: #c8c800;
}
.exampleText2 {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  margin-top: 20px; /* this will remain a margin-top */
  background-color: #c8c800;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="exampleText">Example text</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="exampleText2">Example text</div>
</div>
```

<sup>1</sup>: the link you are using is the MDN page which is a good reference but not the official specification.

Answer (score -1):

> The margin-block-start CSS property defines the logical block start
> margin of an element, which maps to a physical margin depending on the
> element's writing mode, directionality, and text orientation.

**Please run the snippet to see the behavior in action:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
const choice = document.querySelectorAll('.choice');
const target = document.querySelectorAll('.row-target')[0];

choice.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', event => {
  choice.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('selected'));
  event.target.classList.add('selected');
  target.setAttribute('style', event.target.innerText);
}));
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.row {
    height: 33.33%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid #5b6dcd 10px;
    background-color: rgba(229,232,252,.6);
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.row-target {
    border: solid 10px #ffc129;
    background-color: rgba(255,244,219,.6);
}

.transition-all {
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.choice {
background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    margin: .2em 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #d6dee0;
    border-left: 5px solid #d6dee0;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color .2s ease-out,border .2s ease-out;
}

.choice.selected:before {
    opacity: 1;
    right: -1.5em;
}
.choice:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -10px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-left: 10px solid #1b76c4;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}

.selected {
    border-color: #1b76c4;
    border-left-color: #1b76c4;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    transition: height .5s;
    cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="choice selected">
        margin-block-start: 20px; <br>
        writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
    </div>
    
    <div class="choice">
        margin-block-start: 20px;  <br>
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    </div>
    
    <div class="choice">
        margin-block-start: 20%; <br>
        writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
    </div>
    
    <div class="choice">
        margin-block-start: auto; <br>
        writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    </div>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<div id="container">
            <div class="row">One</div>
            <div class="row row-target transition-all" id="example-element" style="margin-block-start: 20px; writing-mode: horizontal-tb;">Two</div>
            <div class="row">Three</div>
        </div>
        
</td></tr>
</table>
```