# Is there a css function that allows me to set the values of top, right, bottom, and left for position all in one line?

Tags: html, css

Not sure, but I seem to recall that there was a way to represent the values of top, right, down, left of positioning in css, like this format: `positioning: top right bottom left`, much like the order of a clock (clockwise). Ex: `Positioning: 10px 20px 10px 30px;`

As an alternative to setting the positions in this way?

```html
<style>
body {
position: relative;
top: 10px;
right: 20px;
bottom: 10px;
left: 30px;
}
</style>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am recalling?

Comment: Are you thinking of other settings, like border-width, margin etc which go clockwise from the top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, it's called `inset`

> This shorthand property sets the top, right, bottom, and left properties. Values are assigned to its sub-properties as for margin. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-logical/#propdef-inset)</sup>

```css
.box {
  position:fixed;
  inset:20px 50px 50% 10px;
  /*
  top:20px;
  right:50px;
  bottom:50%;
  left:10px;
  */
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

---

If you read the specification I linked you will also find more sub properties related to `inset` called *Flow-relative Offsets*

> The `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` **physical properties**, their `inset-block-start`, `inset-block-end`, `inset-inline-start`, `inset-inline-end` **flow-relative** correspondants, and the `inset-block`, `inset-inline`, and `inset` shorthands, are collectively known as the inset properties.

CSS introduces the concept of *flow-relative* property/value to make it easier to deal with different writing modes and directions:

Related: [What is the difference between margin-block-start and margin-top?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59909792/8620333)

---

We can also transform existing property to become relative using the `logical` keyword

> The shorthand properties for margin, padding, and border set values for **physical properties by default**. But authors can specify the `logical` keyword at the beginning of the property value to indicate that the values map to the **flow-relative properties** instead of the physical ones.

This one is still far from having any support: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1282