# ::before and ::after elements overlapping each other ruining the background transparancy

Tags: css, css-position

I have a simple div element that I wanna apply a background shape to it when the user hovers over it by using the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. I rotated these elements with `rotateX()`. How can I style it that the elements shouldn't overlap each other (or at least not ruin the background color) but it should look like a single shape?

Tried using % but didn't work.

Please help.
Thanks so much

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  padding: 18px;
  margin: 10px auto;
/*   border: 1px solid black; */
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
div:hover{
  color:#fff;
}
div:hover::before, div:hover::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #00000050;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}
div::before{
  top:0;
  transform: rotateX(-75deg);
}
div::after{
  bottom:0;
  transform: rotateX(75deg);
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Do the pseudo elements need to be transparent?

Comment: @DM I prefer so

Comment: Try to play with `div::before{ top:0;}` and `div::after{ bottom:0;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A Haworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867454/a-haworth)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69828702/14956277) covers using linear gradient stops to hide the color of half of each pseudo element.

Another approach you could take is to use only one of the pseudo elements with a [polygon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/polygon()) [clip path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to make your shape.

```css
.container { display: flex; }
.hoverable { position: relative; margin: auto; padding: 10px 100px; }

.hoverable:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;

  inset: 0;
  /* top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; */

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 20% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hoverable">Hello, World!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can replace the left/top/bottom/right with only inset:0 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65955682/8620333)

Answer (score 2):

If you make half of each pseudo element only have the color then when you rotate them the colors don't overlap.

A minor adjustment to the padding of the div was needed to get the two rotated 'halves' to meet correctly so this would have to be looked at if you ever went for a responsive rather than a fixed px unit solution.

This snippet removes the background-color from the pseudo elements, instead using a linear-gradient background-image going just half way up (or down) the pseudo element.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 18px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  /*   border: 1px solid black; */
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

div:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

div:hover::before,
div:hover::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}

div::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateX(-75deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#00000050 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%);
}

div:hover::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotateX(75deg);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #00000050 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```