# How to set left and right CSS properties without setting top and bottom

Tags: css

**Is there any way to set just left and right** (of margins, padding, border-width, etc.) **to the same value** without setting the top and bottom at all, **in one expression**, rather than...

```css
.my-class-name { 
  margin-left: 2px; 
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

For properties, if I want the left and right to the same value and my top and bottom to some other value, I can do something like

```css
.my-class-name { margin: 3px 2px; }
```

But to set only the left and right margins, I had thought that there might be a keyword in the vein of `unset` or `inherit` that might be a "unspecified" setting that might let me do something like

```css
.my-class-name { margin: unspecified 2px; }
```

And thus let other earlier CSS take hold on the same selector.  But none of the keywords seem to do this, unless I'm missing something.  I'd also like to know how to do top-and-bottom without left or right, similarly.

So is there a way?  Or would you need some superset of CSS like Sass to do so?

Comment: `margin: auto 30px;` or `margin: 30px auto;` you can if I understand it correctly

Comment: `auto` [is not the same as "not specified"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#values).  I do not want `auto`.

Comment: I know this has been already asnwered... but, just out of curiosity... why not just "margin-top:x;" and  "margin-bottom:x;"

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but SASS wouldn't work, since it would be compiled to CSS anyway, and you'd still be setting the properties. Is there a reason you don't want to use `auto`? I was reading the MDN spec you linked to and it looks `auto` sets the top and bottom to 0, which happens to be the same for `initial`. I realize the browser interprets `auto`, but I would guess that 99.99% of browsers will compute `auto` as 0.

Comment: @disinfor auto will center element if you are working with flexbox and CSS grid. It can easily break your layout

Comment: @TemaniAfif I read the doc you posted to the specs for `flex flow` and that makes more sense. I think this question/title should be updated to add information about Flex/Grid layouts, since that's a key component to the great answer you provided. This would be super helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @disinfor the issue existed before flex: if you want to center a block horizontally and use `margin: auto` it will overwrite any other margin-top and margin-bottom that could have been set elsewhere. Not good.

Comment: @Shautieh I think you misunderstood the original comment and there are also appears to be missing comments on this question. And no, setting `margin: auto` will not overwrite `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` everywhere else, unless the selector is the same and it appears after any `top` or `bottom` margin is set.

Comment: @disinfor it does overwrite margin top and bottom as long as it is applied after. I'm not sure what the original comment was about, but I came to this question while trying to find a solution to my plight, and the margin-inline trick is perfect.

Comment: @Shautieh _it does overwrite margin top and bottom as long as it is applied after._ Yeah, that's how CSS works. I'm glad you got you got a solution to the issue you were having!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by using `margin-inline` or `margin-block`

```css
.box { 
  margin-inline: 10px; /* left and right */
  
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Those properties are called "Flow-relative properties" and they apply to padding, border and more: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-logical/

You don't have to worry about the support as it's pretty good: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_margin-inline

Related:

[What is the difference between margin-block-start and margin-top?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59909792/8620333)

[Is there a css function that allows me to set the values of top, right, bottom, and left for position all in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65955587/8620333)

Comment: Ah, that's new, so that's part of what I want to do.   Looks like there's also `padding-inline` and `padding-block`, and `border-inline-width` and `border-block-width`.  Cool!

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski and also border, border radius and properties that replace width/height

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski `border-inline-width`